# Modulating and transmitting three different voice signals (in MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, audio, digital-communications, modulation, audio-processing

I want to record, modulate and transmit three different voice signals. I will be doing this in MATLAB.
Please can you help me figure out how can I do this?
Or give me a block diagram that can show what exactly I need to do.

Comment: Modulate how and onto what carrier frequency? Is this to be digitized voice signal or analog modulation? There a so many ways to do this so we need more information about your specific application and intent to reduce this to a useful answer.

Comment: Hello Sajjad Ali and welcome to Signal Process SE. In my opinion your question is way too broad and on top of that it seems like you are asking for a solution to your problem. You should at least provide some of your own work and tell people where (and if possible why) you got stuck and what troubles you. Furthermore, as @DanBoschen also states your question lacks clarity and information on the purpose and the approach you would like to follow. I suggest you add some more information to your question and try to be more specific of the various parts comprising it.

Comment: Depending on where you start and what modulation you use, answering your question may take a one semester course. Please narrow it down.